# PHP: If statement matching several values prints nothing, elseif prints a div. Howto?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, multiple-value

Good evening!

Being a total PHP-n00b I'm asking here hoping some clever brain out there can help me out. 
This is the case:

```
<?php if(wpsc_product_count() == 3 ) :?>
<div class="productseparator"></div>     
<?php endif ; ?>
```

Now, what I want out of this is the following:
If *wpsc_product_count* matches 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27 or 30 - I would like it to print nothing at all. Every other value should print the *.productseparator* DIV.

Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use this function:

```
<?php if(wpsc_product_count() % 3 != 0) :?>
<div class="productseparator"></div>     
<?php endif ; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <?php
    echo (wpsc_product_count() % 3 == 0) ? '' : '<div class="productseparator"></div>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!in_array(wpsc_product_count(), array(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30)) {
   echo '<div class="productseparator">';
}
```

relevant [man page here](http://php.net/in_array).

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
<?php
    $cnt = wpsc_product_count();
    if ($cnt > 0 && $cnt <= 30 && % 3 > 0) {
        print '<div class="productseparator"></div>';
    }
?>
```

using the '%' operator will give you the remainder of a/b.